# Call a method into the class React ES6

Tags: reactjs, es6-class

I have the following react class

```
export default class ValClass { 
    getValue (key) {
       return key;
    }
}

import React from 'react'
import ValClass from 'valclass'

export class Content extends React.Component {       

    render() {
        let value = ValClass.getValue(this.props.valueKey);
        return <span dangerouslySetInnerHTML={{__html: value}} />
    }
}
```

> But I have the following error:
>
> TypeError: _valClass2.default.getValue is not a function.

If i code like this

```
export default class ValClass { }
ValClass.getValue (key) {
   return key;
}

import React from 'react'
import ValClass from 'valclass'

export class Content extends React.Component {       

    render() {
        let value = ValClass.getValue(this.props.valueKey);
        return <span dangerouslySetInnerHTML={{__html: value}} />
    }
}
```

Then its working fine. How?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Reason is, you defined that **function as static**, directly using [this](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/this) keyword it will not be accessible.

As per [DOC](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Classes/static):

> Static method calls are made directly on the class and are not callable
> on instances of the class.
>
> Static methods are not directly accessible using the [this](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/this) keyword from
> non-static methods. You need to call them using the class name:
> CLASSNAME.STATIC_METHOD_NAME() or by calling the method as a property
> of the constructor: this.constructor.STATIC_METHOD_NAME().
>
> In order to call a static method within another static method of the
> same class, you can use the [this](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/this) keyword.

In you case i think you don't need a `static` method, instead of defining that as a `static`, write it like this:

```js
class Content extends React.Component {

   getValue() {
      return "<div> Hello </div>";
   }

   render() {
      let value = this.getValue();
      return <div dangerouslySetInnerHTML={{__html: value}} />
   }
}

ReactDOM.render(<Content/>, document.getElementById('app'))
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/react/15.1.0/react.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/react/15.1.0/react-dom.min.js"></script>

<div id='app'/>
```

**Update:**

You changed the original question, if you defined another class and want to call a function of that then you need to define that as static.

```js
class Content extends React.Component {

   render() {
      let value = App.getValue();
      return <div dangerouslySetInnerHTML={{__html: value}} />
   }
}

class App {
   static getValue() {
      return "<div> Hello </div>";
   }
}

ReactDOM.render(<Content/>, document.getElementById('app'))
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/react/15.1.0/react.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/react/15.1.0/react-dom.min.js"></script>

<div id='app'/>
```

Comment: I have checked after removing static, the error is still there :(

Comment: you used the same code that i suggested in answer ? it should work.

Comment: check the updated answer, update section of answer it will work :), don't change the original ques because after that all the answer will not make any sense, to update the ques write a Edit section and inside that mention the another problem.

Answer (score 2):

Please add [`static`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Classes/static) keyword if you want to use the `getValue` in a static context when calling `ValClass.getValue`.

```js
class ValClass { 
    static getValue (key) {
        return key;
    }
}

class Content extends React.Component {
   render() {
       let value = ValClass.getValue(this.props.valueKey);
       return <span dangerouslySetInnerHTML={{__html: value}} />
   }
}

ReactDOM.render(<Content valueKey="<strong>Hello</strong>" />, document.getElementById('app'))
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/react/15.1.0/react.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/react/15.1.0/react-dom.min.js"></script>

<div id='app'/>
```

Answer (score 0):

You have to call static-methods with "this.constructor."

So it would be

```
this.constructor.getValue(this.props.valueKey);
```